# Firefox 5 and PDF

Tags: pdf, firefox

I heard that Firefox 5 had introduced support for native PDF reading but I tried opening a PDF link and it continues trying to ask me where to download the PDF.

Is this feature supposed to work only with specific PDF versions or should I activate some hidden settings?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can see that they [mention it](http://www.conceivablytech.com/6581/products/firefox-5-social-sharing-home-tab-pdf-viewer-tab-apps)

> 6. In-browser preview: Firefox will also get an integrated PDF viewer
>      (like Chrome) and will extend this
>      capability to more popular file
>      formats, including MP3.

Unfortuantly this doesn't look like the feature has been released yet.

In the [mean time](http://support.mozilla.com/en-US/kb/Opening%20PDF%20files%20within%20Firefox)

Answer (score 2):

It's not here yet, but I believe that the plan is to bake PDF support in by using HTML5 + JavaScript, out to an SVG or `<canvas>` backend.  See [PDF.js](https://wiki.mozilla.org/PDF.js).